# Issue with function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called 'subject_101' and for the time being it has three columns, **'id'** which has a sequence against it, **'date_created'** which has 'SET DEFAULT now()' applied to it and finally a column called **'reference'**. I've been successful in creating an update statement which joins the **'id'** and **'date_created'** fields using;

```
UPDATE test.subject_101 set reference = id || '/' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_created));
```

and this produces the desired result. e.g *4/2014*

I wanted to be a bit smarter and create this as a function/trigger but i'm having issues with the below code. What seems to happen is that when I insert a new record my **'reference'** column remains NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reference_number()
            RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
            BEGIN
                IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                 NEW.reference = id || '/' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_created));
                END IF;
                RETURN NEW; 
            END;
            $$ language 'plpgsql'

CREATE TRIGGER create_reference_number BEFORE UPDATE ON test.subject_101
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE reference_number();
```

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: I think in a before trigger the `ID` column will not yet be populated and therefor the concatenation will yield NULL. Try an after update trigger

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid creating such a column entirely, and instead generate it with a view on demand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this trigger to fire on INSERT's on the table which I gather from the implementation of your function you should create the trigger with BEFORE INSERT not BEFORE UPDATE

BEFORE UPDATE means it only fires on UPDATE statements.

BTW i'm with Craig Ringer that it is in general not a good idea to create such a column.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative? All reference systems where I work as incremental followed by year e.g 4/2014